# How do i make the Printwriter not wait for an input

Tags: java

Background and Issue:

I have built a library system which sends information between a mySQL database. I have a printwriter "out" and a scanner that im using for a client and server class. However, im having trouble understanding how to make the printwriter break out of the while loop which makes it wait for an input. Is there a way to have the PrintWriter not have to wait for an input and move onto my bookStoreMenu(); method in the server class.

Client:

```
socket = new Socket(IPaddress, port);
System.out.println("Connected to server at "+ IPaddress + ":" + port);
//Connect a Scanner to the socket's InputStream to read lines from it
in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
//Connect a PrintWriter to the OutputStream to send lines to server
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
//Connect a Scanner to system input to take command line instructions
menu();

userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while(userInput.hasNext()){
    out.println(userInput.nextLine());//handle output to server
    System.out.println(in.nextLine()); //print input from server
}
```

Server:

```
 while (sqlExecute.next()) {
     int id = sqlExecute.getInt("bookID");
     String isbn = sqlExecute.getString("book_ISBN");
     String title = sqlExecute.getString("book_title");
     String author = sqlExecute.getString("book_author");
     String publisher = sqlExecute.getString("book_publisher");
     String language = sqlExecute.getString("book_language");
     //Building a string
     /*BookString = ("Book ISBN: " + isbn + ", Book Title: " + title + ",
         Author: " + author + ", Publisher: " + publisher + ", Language " +
        language);*/
     bookResults.append("BookID: " +id + ", Book ISBN: " + isbn);
     bookResults.append(", Title: " + title + ", Author: " + author);
     bookResults.append(", Publisher: " + publisher + ", Language: " + language);
     bookResults.append(" || ");
     System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", 
                       id, isbn, title, author, publisher, language + "\n");
}
//Sending results
out.println(bookResults + "\n");
bookStoreMenu();
```

I have tried adding new lines using "\n" to also print to new lines but the printwriter also seems to not like this.

I have tried making various loops and boolean statements within the client and server but haven't managed to figure it out.

Comment: A `PrintWriter` never waits for any input, it does purely output. If anything, then it's the `Scanner` that you use that waits for input (via the `InputStream` you used to construct it).

Comment: You need to arrange things in a sequence of prompt->action„ prompt->action ... The prompt will always wait for input